# Trying to use own dataset on Lasagne basic example (slightly modified) to make neural network for face recognition

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, lasagne

I'm doing the basic lasagne example:
https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/examples/mnist.py

which I've modified slightly by combining it with another similar example.

I'm trying to run the CNN model, where I've added some extra input to the CNN def, but it shouldn't be any different. Also changed the default value of 28 for the input layer in the example to 60 (for height and width), classes is being used later on in the code, but the code "hangs" on at that last network line, meaning the code is still running, but nothing is happening.
[Output when running the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJkBC.png) The input_var is defined as such in the mainloop:

```
input_var = T.tensor4('input_var')
```

rest of the code:

```
def build_cnn(classes, height, width, input_var=None):

    print("Input layer, with height: {}, width: {} and input var: {}".format(height, width, input_var))

    network = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape = (None, 1, height, width),
                                    input_var=input_var)


    print("Convolutional layer with 32 kernels of size 5x5")
    network = lasagne.layers.Conv2DLayer(network,
                                         num_filters = 32,
                                         filter_size = (5, 5),
                                         nonlinearity = lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
                                         W = lasagne.init.HeNormal(gain = 'relu'))
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, based on what I've tried so far it seems to be my own dataset that is the problem. I've reshaped my dataset to match the MNIST dataset where for ex. X_train has the shape [images, channel, height, width]. Where channel = 1 and height, width = 60. The code for retrieving these is:

```
def load_images():
    dataset_path = os.path.abspath("C:/Users/laende/Dropbox/Skole UiS/4. semester/Master/Master/data/test_database")
    [bilder, label, names] = read_images1(dataset_path, (28, 28))
    label = np.array(label)

    bilder = bilder / np.float32(256)
    bilder = bilder[:, newaxis, :, :]

    X_train1, X_test1, Y_train1, Y_test1 = train_test_split(bilder, label, test_size = 0.2)

    list_of_labels = list(xrange(max(label) + 1))
    classes = len(list_of_labels)

    return X_train1, X_test1, Y_train1, Y_test1, classes
```

where read_images1 is:

```
 def read_images1(path, sz = None, channel = None):
    c = 0
    X = []
    y = []
    folder_names = []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames, in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            folder_names.append(subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                try:
                    im = cv2.imread(os.path.join(subject_path, filename),     cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

                    if (sz is not None):
                        im = cv2.resize(im, sz)

                    X.append(np.asarray(im, dtype = np.uint8))
                    y.append(c)

                except IOError, (errno, strerror):
                    print "I/O error ({0]): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
                except:
                    print "unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
                    raise
            c = c + 1
    return [X, y, folder_names]
```

The code in main which is ran:

```
def main(model='mlp', num_epochs=100):
    # Load the dataset

    print("Loading data...")
    mnist = 1
    if mnist == 1:
        classes = 10
        X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test = load_dataset()

        dataset = {
            'train': {'X': X_train, 'y': y_train},
            'test': {'X': X_test, 'y': y_test}}
        shape = dataset['train']['X'][0].shape

    else:
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, classes = load_images()

        dataset = {
            'train': {'X': X_train, 'y': y_train},
            'test': {'X': X_test, 'y': y_test}}
        shape = dataset['train']['X'][0].shape

    input_var = T.tensor4('inputs')
    target_var = T.ivector('targets')

    print("Building model and compiling functions...")
    if model == 'mlp':
        network = build_mlp(height=int(shape[1]),
                            width=int(shape[2]),
                            channel=int(shape[0]),
                            classes=int(classes),
                            input_var=input_var)
```

if mnist = 1 (in main) the code runs fine, if I try with my own dataset it gets stuck at in build_mlp (similar to original problem with cnn):

```
def build_mlp(classes, channel, height, width, input_var=None):

    neurons = int(height * width)

    network = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape = (None, channel, height, width),
                                 input_var=input_var)

    network = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(network, p = 0.2)

   #Code gets stuck on this point, running forever, doing nothing.
   #No error messages received either.
    network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
        network,
        num_units = neurons,
        nonlinearity = lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
        W = lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())
```

**EDIT 2:**
Afters struggling with this for a while I found out that the the image resizing done in read_images1() caused the problem:

```
 def read_images1(path, sz = None, channel = None):
    c = 0
    X = []
    y = []
    folder_names = []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames, in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            folder_names.append(subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                try:
                    im = cv2.imread(os.path.join(subject_path, filename),     cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                    #This part caused the problems. 
                    if (sz is not None):
                        im = cv2.resize(im, sz)

                    X.append(np.asarray(im, dtype = np.uint8))
                    y.append(c)

                except IOError, (errno, strerror):
                    print "I/O error ({0]): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
                except:
                    print "unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
                    raise
            c = c + 1
    return [X, y, folder_names]
```

If I didn't pass any resizing and used the default image sizes that were in the folders, the neural network was able to compile. Does anyone have any idea why? I updated the read_images1() to this:

```
 def read_images1(path, sz = None, na = False):
    """

    :param path: sti til mappe med underliggende mapper tilhørende personer.
    :param sz: Størrelse på bildefilene
    :return: returnerer liste av bilder, labels og navn
    """
    c = 0
    X = []
    y = []
    folder_names = []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames, in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            folder_names.append(subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                try:
                    im = cv2.imread(os.path.join(subject_path, filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

                    if (sz is not None):
                        im = cv2.resize(im, dsize=sz, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

                    if (na == True):
                        im = im[newaxis, :, :]


                    X.append(np.asarray(im, dtype = np.uint8))
                    y.append(c)

                except IOError, (errno, strerror):
                    print "I/O error ({0]): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
                except:
                    print "unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
                    raise
            c = c + 1
    return [X, y, folder_names]
```

If I run the program with sz = None and na = True, then it works. If any size is given to the sz parameter the code gets stuck trying to compile the neural network again.

Comment: Can you post your complete code somewhere?  I think you posted all the modified pieces here but it is a little hard to follow.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/iGke965B)

Didn't include the rest that comes after the network has been built, as that's where it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I can see a few issues here, not sure which one you're running into...

1. In `read_images1()`, X is a python list of numpy arrays.  Where does it get converted to a single numpy array?  Try adding `X = numpy.asarray(X)`.  You also need to reshape it to (n_images, n_channels, width, height) where I assume n_channels=1 for grayscale.  The network expects 4D input not 3D.
2. This code `list_of_labels = list(xrange(max(label) + 1)); classes = len(list_of_labels)` assumes the labels are sequential numbers from 0 to N.  Are they?
3. Your `build_mlp(classes, height, width, input_var=None)` is pretty different from the original example `build_mlp(input_var=None)`.  The original example clearly works, so whatever is wrong has to do with the differences.  One of the big differences is that you keep assigning to the same variable, like this `network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(network, ...)` where the original has different variables for each layer `l_hid1 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_in_drop, ...)`
4. Also, if it hangs during `build_mlp()` then clearly the problem is not in how you read images.  Try using the original version of `build_mlp()` with your images.  Try running it by itself. Skip the image reading, just call `build_mlp()` with constant parameters.

Comment: 1. Changed read_images1(): http://pastebin.com/dRUe7EmT

2. printing list_of_labels and classes: 
list_of_labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
classes: 16

which is correct.

3. I know it's different, but running the MNIST dataset through that works flawlessly, meaning the network itself isn't the issue. 

4. The issue is how my dataset is "setup", in regards of type and probably how the 4D matrix is built. 

With the change to read_image1() it still wont create the network, stopping at the first layer after the input layer.

Comment: Also a print of X_train and y_train for MNIST and my dataset:
http://bildr.no/image/ME00RFpt.jpeg

Comment: What I did notice was that the y_train, y_test for my dataset has double spaces, which is a result from using the test_train_split. Not sure if that has anything to say though. Also a print of 1 image from each dataset:

http://pastebin.com/AUZTGiF7

Comment: Is there a way to see where the code "hangs" internally? I mean, I get no error messages when running, it just hangs at a specific point when building the network and it'll run endlessly until I stop the code. It's impossible for me to see what's wrong, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Okay, so by not using cv2.resize the code worked fine with my own dataset. I'm still not sure why, but it solved my problem at least.

Meaning I didnt pass anything for sz here: 
def read_images1(path, sz = None, channel = None):

Comment: Accepted your answer, but resizing the images still results in the neural network not compiling / building. Ty for help. :)